# Using jQuery .prepend combined with some PHP

Tags: jquery

Im using some basic jQuery and PHP to generate a list of image to use in a jQuery slideshow.

Here is the PHP and HTML:

```
<div id="coin-slider-holder">
        <div id="coin-slider">

            <?php
                $url = "$CFG->themewww"."/".current_theme()."/images.xml";
                $xmlstr = file_get_contents($url);
                $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);  
                $images = array();

                foreach ($xml->image as $image) {
                     $id = (string)$image->id;
                     $images[$id] = array(
                         'id'     => (string)$image->id,
                         'link'     => (string)$image->href,
                         'src'     => (string)$image->source,
                         'title' => (string)$image->title,
                         'alt'     => (string)$image->alt
                     );
                 }

                 ksort($images);

                 foreach ($images as $image){
                     echo "<a href='".$image['src']."'><img src='".$image['src']."' alt='".$image['alt']."'/>";
                     echo "<span>".$image['title']."</span></a>";
                 }
             ?> 

        </div>
    </div>
```

This all works, however I want to insert this HTML and PHP at a specific point in the page which I can edit.

Im looking at using:

```
$('#site-index .sitetopic').prepend('<p>Insert jQuery Slider Here</p>');
```

But can I use .prepend to insert the above code?

Comment: I don't see the element with the ID "site-index" or class "sitetopic" ... are you missing some html?

Comment: That where i want to insert the code.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code: http://jsfiddle.net/pzn6q/ As you can see, it's possible to use that PHP code to generate content of `.prepend`'s argument.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use .prepend() here. If you want to make a dynamic gallery then it would be better if you use jQuery AJAX. Do something like the following in the AJAX response-

```
$('#showGallery').prepend(respText);
```

Here, showGallery is the id of the DIV or Table you want to show your PHP code  and respText is you AJAX response with PHP code.

Checkout the following URL to have more details about .prepend()

http://api.jquery.com/prepend/